# Which icon library we should use in react-native mobile app

Tags: react-native

I want use a icon library in my react-native app but I am not able to find any library apart from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ant-design/icons-react-native

Comment: Can you update your question with a code example and more information please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most popular and required by other libraries
[react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

It support all the icons and you find it from
[here](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/)

Answer (score 1):

My vote is for Font Awesome Icon. Their free tier comes with a lot of good stuff and their node package is really easy to use.

[Font Awesome NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fontawesome)